# Solution of the first order differential equation $y'=\frac{x(x^2+y^2)^2}{4y}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I m stuck in finding the solution of the following differential equation

$$y'=\frac{x(x^2+y^2)^2}{4y}.$$

Please give me some hint.

Comment: I would try, y = ux, y' = u'x + u and turn this into a separable diff eq.

Comment: Is it homogoneous differential equation?

Comment: hint: write equation as $\frac{4yy'}{(y^2+x^2)^2}=x$ then change the variable: $y^2+x^2=h^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{4yy'}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=x$

then define $x^2+y^2=h^2 \Rightarrow 2hh'=2yy'+2x \Rightarrow y'=\frac{hh'-x}{y}$

then by substituting we get: $\frac{4(hh'-x)}{h^4}=x \Rightarrow4(hh'-x)=xh^4 \Rightarrow \frac{4hh'}{4+h^4}=x$

now define $g=h^2$ and solve the problem: $\Rightarrow g'=2hh'$
$$\frac{2g}{4+g^2}=x \Rightarrow \tan^{-1}(\frac{g}{2})=\frac{x^2}{2}+C \Rightarrow g=2\tan(\frac{x^2}{2}+C)$$
then we get: $$h=\pm \sqrt{2\tan(\frac{x^2}{2}+C)} \Rightarrow y=\pm \sqrt{ 2\tan(\frac{x^2}{2}+C)-x^2}$$

Comment: very clever, a well deserved (+1). btw $\tan$ looks nicer then $tan$ just add an additional \ in front

Comment: ok thanks for feedback.

Comment: That inner square root should not be there because $y^2=h^2-x^2$, not $h-x^2$. Otherwise OK outside of typos.

Comment: very nice answer, you really deserve +1

Answer (score 0):

let $$ x^2 + y^2=k $$
then $$ y'=k'/2y-(x/y) $$
so $$ k'/2y-x/y=(k^2/4)x/y$$
=> $$dk/(k^2/2+2)=xdx$$
=> $$arctan(k/2)=x^2/2+c$$
so, $$ arctan(x^2/2+y^2/2)=x^2/2 + c$$